# Tabindex is not working in ibiza framework

Tags: azure, accessibility

I am developing a azure extension in ibiza framwork. My application require tabindex in div.
But some how ibiza framwork sanitize tabindex. 
How can i overcome this problem

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share your code

Answer (score 0):

- To get tabindex added to your elements, map their behavior to either  or  in combination with the fxClick binding.
- Ibiza sanitizes the tabindex from code due to some accessibility errors (not sure what are they).

So only probable work around for now is to use the anchor or button to get it workedout.